# How to create an object of a relationship in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Hey I need to create a relationship in sequelize. I have the model and is well created in the database.
I'll show you my models but it's not very relevant.

**Seller Model**

```
const Sellers = db.define("sellers", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  surname: Sequelize.STRING,
});

Sellers.hasMany(Clients);
module.exports = Sellers;
```

**Client Model**

```
const Client = db.define("clients", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  creationDate: Sequelize.DATE,
  client_type: Sequelize.STRING,
});

module.exports = Client;
```

**What I want to do** is simply make a relation between the client and seller. In the database a SellerId is added in the client table because of sequelize `hasMany()` method. What I want to do is just be able to pass the id to the ORM when creating a client so it makes the relationship automatically to the seller table.

[Sequelize Documentation about this](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html)

Thank you for taking your time to read this. I hope you can help me! Have a great day.

Comment: Do you need to create a new client linked to an already existing seller?

Comment: Thanks for replying!. Yes, That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd prefer to define a foreign key column  in a model and indicate it in associations explicitly. And of course you need to add another association from `clients` to `sellers` - `belongsTo` and call both of associations outside models to be able to reference them to each other.

Client model file:

```js
const Client = db.define("clients", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  creationDate: Sequelize.DATE,
  client_type: Sequelize.STRING,
  sellerId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false // or true if this association is optional
  },
});
```

some `database.js` file where you should register all associations:

```js
....
Sellers.hasMany(Clients, { foreignKey: 'sellerId' });
Clients.belongsTo(Sellers, { foreignKey: 'sellerId' });
```

And then you can create a client indicating a seller's id:

```js
const seller = await Seller.findOne({
  where: {
    name: 'Peter'
  }
})
const newClient = await Client.create({
   name: 'John',
   sellerId: seller.id,
   // other fields here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great response! I have a question, why the foreignKey: 'sellerId' when making the relation of the seller to the clients? wouldn't it create a field in the Sellers table called 'sellerId'?

Comment: No. A `foreignKey` option in `hasMany` indicates a field in a passed model as first argument (`Clients` in this case)